# How do I prevent code injection attack on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, code-injection

I keep having to restart my server due to excessive CPU and Memory usage. On further investigation I have noticed that just before this happens I get injection attacks similar to the following:

```
http://www.example.com/\x15\x03\x03\x00\x1A2<\xB4\x02\x89\x1A[\x1F\x9C\x0FG\xF8\x18*\xBCC\x98o\xD7\x1C*\x83[\xA3\xFB\x1E
```

What is this and how do I stop it?

The server is using Nginx and PHP-FPM.

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed similar last night - somebody POSTing something that, when decoded, looks like this:

`cgi-bin/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n`

Looks like probing for 0-day, though I'm far from any conclusions :-)

Comment: By the way - I inserted your URL string to php deobfuscator (https://www.unphp.net/decode) and got something like this: 

`<?  2<[G*Co*[ ?>`

Comment: Tried this on my server and my nginx returns usual error: `curl -X POST 'https://my.site.example.com/\\x15\\x03\\x03\\x00\\x1A2<\\xB4\\x02\\x89\\x1A\[\\x1F\\x9C\\x0FG\\xF8\\x18*\\xBCC\\x98o\\xD7\\x1C*\\x83\[\\xA3\\xFB\\x1E'` - might this be your application allowing this kind of input?

Comment: I'm still clueless as to what it might be doing but nothing unusual there! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The deobfuscated code does not seem to be a correct code snippet. In my opinion somebody could be testing if your application would execute code injected through POST /or/ they already have something implanted within your application that would respond.